# Fatfree Framework nested Templates

Tags: fat-free-framework

Trying to wrap my head around Fatfree and how I can nest templates using data from the DB.
So far I have a home page loading that loads three templates. So good so far and everything works.

Main class

```
function homePage($f3){
   $f3->set('slider','slider.html');
   $f3->set('testimonials','testimonials.html');
   $f3->set('cardContainer','cardContainer.html');
   echo Template::instance()->render('home.html');
}
```

Home.html

```
<include href="{{ @slider }}" />
<include href="{{ @testimonials }}" />
<include href="{{ @cardContainer }}" />
```

CardContainer needs to load cards containing images and other text that are stored in the DB. I can get those rows from the DB no problem in the Main class and var_dump them to the view.

How ever I'm not understanding how I add that data to a card template and then insert that card into the cardContainer? I'm not even sure what I need to be looking for to make this possible. Any direction would be much appriciated. If this was done in straight up PHP I would be done by now.

Thanks for any help or guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would pull them out of your database and do one of 2 things:

```php
<?php
// option 1
function homePage($f3){
   $cards = $f3->db->getYourCardsOrWhatever();
   $f3->set('cards', $cards);
   $f3->set('slider','slider.html');
   $f3->set('testimonials','testimonials.html');
   // then in here you would reference @cards in a <repeat> element
   $f3->set('cardContainer','cardContainer.html');
   echo Template::instance()->render('home.html');
}

// option 2
?>
<include href="{{ @slider }}" />
<include href="{{ @testimonials }}" />
<include href="{{ @cardContainer }}" with="cards={{ @cards_from_somewhere_to_inject }}" />
```

Comment: So I have the <repeat> working. Thanks for that. But I have to say this is one ugly frame work. It really doesn't make anything cleaner than just using PHP as it is just forcing the usage of another syntax that is completely foreign to every other language that I have ever known. 

But it works and I thank you for that.

Comment: @PaulNeale if you're more happy with a near PHP experience in the templates, just go for the View or Preview engine in fatfree.. (F3 comes with 3 template engines included!) https://fatfreeframework.com/3.7/preview

Comment: @PaulNeale I suppose it could be considered ugly in the sense that it doesn't follow the typical format you'd expect. Once you understand what's going on, F3 has a ton of flexibility and I find myself seeking the documentation less and less (because I understand it's just simple syntax that gets parsed back to PHP). I found myself going to Twigs documentation over and over and over again cause I kept forgetting how to make something work.